# Tracker column that returns value based on sum of other column ranges

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new column that returns the types of exams ordered, if any SAT exams were ordered and any PSAT exams were ordered.

Input:

```
  PSAT Standard PSAT Non-Standard SAT Standard Grade 11 SAT Non-Standard Grade 11 SAT Standard Grade 12 SAT Non-Standard Grade 12
0             -                 -                   YES                       YES                     -                         -
1           YES                 -                   YES                       YES                     -                       YES
2           YES               YES                   YES                       YES                     -                         -
3           YES               YES                   YES                       YES                     -                         -
4             -                 -                   YES                         -                   YES                         -
5             -                 -                   YES                         -                     -                         -
6           YES               YES                   YES                       YES                     -                         -
7           YES                 -                   YES                         -                     -                         -
```

Desired output (new column at the end):

```
ORDERED EXAM
0          SAT
1    SAT, PSAT
2    SAT, PSAT
3    SAT, PSAT
4          SAT
5          SAT
6    SAT, PSAT
7    SAT, PSAT
```

My current code is not working because Pandas throws an error at my syntax; `KeyError: "['PSAT Standard':'PSAT Non-Standard']"`

```py
def ordered_exam(psat_cols, sat_cols):
    msg = []
    ordered_psat = np.where('Y' in df.loc[:,psat_cols])
    ordered_sat = np.where('Y' in df.loc[:,sat_cols])
    if ordered_psat:
        msg.append('PSAT')
    if ordered_sat:
        msg.append('SAT')
    if not msg:
        return None
    else:
        return ', '.join(msg)
df['ORDERED EXAM'] = df['ORDERED EXAM'].apply(ordered_exam("['PSAT Standard':'PSAT Non-Standard']",
                                                             "['SAT Standard Grade 11':'SAT Non-Standard Grade 12']"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### slicing based on expected location:

```
def test(x):
    ordered_exam = list()
    if 'YES' in x[0:2]:
        ordered_exam.append('PSAT')
    if 'YES' in x[2:]:
        ordered_exam.append('SAT')
    return ordered_exam

df['ordered_exam'] = df.apply(lambda x: test(x.to_list()), axis=1)
```

[image]

---

#### using column headers:

```
def test(x, y):
    psat_list = [z for z in y if 'PSAT' in z]
    sat_list = list(set(y) - set(psat_list))
    ordered_exam = list()
    if 'YES' in x[psat_list].to_list():
        ordered_exam.append('PSAT')
    if 'YES' in x[sat_list].to_list():
        ordered_exam.append('SAT')
    return ordered_exam

df['ordered_exam'] = df.apply(lambda x: test(x, df.columns), axis=1)
```

Comment: I hoped for a solution where I could select the columns by name, but this works fine.

Comment: @ChristinaZhou I've updated the solution with an option that uses the column headers instead of index slicing.